# Apagando item de uma lista sem saber seu índice - Python

Tags: python

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte lista:

```py
lista_de_dados = [['nome', 'prioridade', 'hora', 'consultório', 'Número na fila'],
                  ['Gabriel', 'Comum', '16:30', 'Dermatologia', 1]
                  ['Gabrielle', 'Preferencial', '16:31', 'Dermatologia', 2]]
```

E eu queira criar uma função para apagar uma dessas listas dentro da lista_de_dados sem apagar as outras. Por exemplo, supondo que eu queira apagar a lista que contem as informações de Gabrielle. Eu poderia fazer:

```py
lista_de_dados = [['nome', 'prioridade', 'hora', 'consultório', 'Número na fila'],
                  ['Gabriel', 'Comum', '16:30', 'Dermatologia', 1],
                  ['Gabrielle', 'Preferencial', '16:31', 'Dermatologia', 2]]
lista_de_dados.__delitem__(2)
print(lista_de_dados)
```

Irá mostrar na tela:

```py
[['nome', 'prioridade', 'hora', 'consultório', 'Número na fila'], ['Gabriel', 'Comum', '16:30', 'Dermatologia', 1]]
```

Contudo como eu posso apagar o mesmo item (a lista com as informações de Gabrielle) sem saber a posição dela na lista_de_dados? Por exemplo, eu sei apenas o que tem dentro da lista que contem as informações de Gabrielle mas não sei a posição dela em relação a lista_de_dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode identificar o item que você está interessado pelo index e usar o *try statement* para lidar com o erro que surge quando ele não encontrar o item na sublista. Veja:

```
lista_de_dados = [['nome', 'prioridade', 'hora', 'consultório', 'Número na fila'],
                  ['Gabriel', 'Comum', '16:30', 'Dermatologia', 1],
                  ['Gabrielle', 'Preferencial', '16:31', 'Dermatologia', 2]]

ans = input('Por favor, me dê o nome cujo os dados você pretende apagar:')
for i in range(len(lista_de_dados)):
    try:
        lista_de_dados[i].index(ans)
        lista_de_dados.__delitem__(i)
        print('A sublista {} foi deletada'.format(i))

    except:
        print('A sublista {} permanece em lista_de_dados'.format(i))

print(lista_de_dados)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar `for` loop e ir verificando se o primeiro item da lista de dados (nome) é igual ao nome que o usuário digitou. Se for igual, você pode apagar essa lista de dados utilizando o método de listas `remove(value)`. Exemplo:

```
lista_de_dados = [['nome', 'prioridade', 'hora', 'consultório', 'Número na fila'],
                  ['Gabriel', 'Comum', '16:30', 'Dermatologia', 1],
                  ['Gabrielle', 'Preferencial', '16:31', 'Dermatologia', 2]]

nome = input('Nome do perfil que será apagado:')

for perfil in lista_de_dados:

    if perfil[0] == nome:
        lista_de_dados.remove(perfil)
        break

print(lista_de_dados)
```